# How to provide temporary credentials (Access Key/ID session token) to aws node?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, node-red

I have certificates file for device registered in AWS IOT. I want to use this certificate to access AWS Services. It works as I expected when I use boto3.

Now  would like to transfer the operation to Node-RED. I installed AWS s3 Node in node-red. But, it asks only Access Key and Secret Key. How to pass Session token along with that?

[image]

How to use temporary credential to access S3 bucket?

Comment: Seems it does not support IAM roles. Thus you have to create IAM user with just enough permissions for node-red to work.